# Quelle forme pour « on prend "y" tel que "x"... » ?

Tags: usage, mathématiques, subjonctif

Doit-on dire « on prend y tel que x *est* égal à 5 » ou « on prend y tel que x *soit* égal à 5 » ?
Il me semble que la seconde option est préférable mais j'ai déjà entendu la première.

La première est-elle fausse ou correcte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La première sonne faux. Certains énoncés mathématiques peuvent être écrits comme ça, mais c'est une erreur.

La seconde est correcte, et est la forme qui doit être utilisée:

> on prend y tel que x **soit** égal à 5

Explications (par [Vincent G](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/8187/vincent-g)):

Si la subordonnée introduite par tel que est une subordonnée de comparaison, l'emploi de l'indicatif est nécessaire dans celle-ci. Dans ce cas tel que exprime la similitude ou introduit un exemple, tel que je viens de l'écrire.

En revanche, si la subordonnée introduite est une subordonnée de conséquence, c'est le subjonctif qui est requis dans la subordonnée, est on est dans ce cas là pour la phrase citée en exemple dans la question.

(sources : [Le Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tel/77019?q=tel+que#76118))

Answer (score 3):

Si la subordonnée introduite par `tel que` est une subordonnée de comparaison, l'emploi de l'indicatif est nécessaire dans celle-ci. Dans ce cas `tel que` exprime la similitude ou introduit un exemple, tel que je viens de l'écrire.

En revanche, si la subordonnée introduite est une subordonnée de conséquence, c'est le subjonctif qui est requis dans la subordonnée, est on est dans ce cas là pour la phrase citée en exemple dans la question.

(sources : http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tel/77019?q=tel+que#76118)

Answer (score 2):

**La seconde est la bonne forme, la première est incorrecte.**

La règle dépasse les mathématiques:

phrase d'action + tel que (**dans le sens de but**) => **subjonctif** dans la seconde phrase.

Ce lien fournit tout une série d'exemples: http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/C_b_emploi_subj.htm

On peut garder le **même sens** en remplaçant *tel que* par *afin que*, *pour que*, *de (telle) sorte que*,  *de façon (à ce) que*, *de manière que*,  :

> on prend y afin que x **soit** égal à 5.
>
> on prend y pour que x **soit** égal à 5.
>
> je ferme les portes tel qu'il soit impossible d'entrer => il sera impossible d'entrer.

A contrario, on peut avoir un indicatif, s'il n'y a pas de sens de but, mais simplement une affirmation:

> Je le dis tel que je le **fais**.
>
> je ferme les portes tel qu'il **est** impossible d'entrer => au moment où je ferme les portes, *on voit bien* qu'il est impossible d'entrer.

Comment: Le « *x* est égal à 5 » qui apparait dans une telle phrase n'est pas nécessairement un but. Le présenter comme tel peut souvent induire le lecteur en erreur et je pense que c'est la raison de l'emploi fréquent de l'indicatif dans de tels cas en mathématiques.